# JSONArray is null while retreiving from JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON:

```
{
    "Bills": {
        "name": "Mr.X",
        "creditCardNumber": "1234567890",
        "billDetails": [{
                "PaymentDueDate": "07-03-2018",
                "StatementDate": "24-02-2018",
                "AmountDue": "2156"
            },
            {
                "PaymentDueDate": "05-02-2018",
                "StatementDate": "23-01-2018",
                "AmountDue": "3256"
            },
            {
                "PaymentDueDate": "07-01-2018",
                "StatementDate": "24-12-2017",
                "AmountDue": "1132"
            },
            {
                "PaymentDueDate": "07-12-2017",
                "StatementDate": "24-10-2017",
                "AmountDue": "7654"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to read the JSON object but getting null for JSONArray i.e. billDetailsArr

```
 public static void readJSONFile() throws java.text.ParseException {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


            JSONObject data;
            try {
                data = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("\\Bills.json"));
                JSONArray billdetailsArr = (JSONArray) data.get("billDetails");

                for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
            {

                JSONObject jsonobj_2 = (JSONObject) billdetailsArr.get(i);
                String dateStr = (String) jsonobj_2.get(new Date("StatementDate"));
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date StatementDate = sdf.parse(dateStr);
            }
}
```

My POJO class is:

```
public class BillDetails {

    private Date PaymentDueDate;
    private Date StatementDate;
    private String AmountDue;
}
```

I want to have StatementDate & PaymentDueDate in date format not as String. Is my code correct?

Comment: Post your error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The billDetails array isn't a property of the root element - it's an element within the bills element. So you need to get the bills element and then get the billsDetail array off that.

e.g.

```
data = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("\\Bills.json"));
JSONObject billsObj = (JSONObject)data.get("bills");
JSONArray billdetailsArr = (JSONArray)billsObj.get("billDetails");
```